Spelling Bee game regex
In the NYTimes Spelling Bee game, you have to make words (4+ letters long) using a set of 7 letters, one of which must be used in the word. This is fairly trivial to make a regex for:
grep '^[bluntam]\{4,\}$' /usr/share/dict/words | grep u

(All lowercase to avoid acronyms and proper nouns) Is there a way to combine these into one fancy regex? The issue with putting the required letter in the center, like [bluntam]*u[bluntam]* is that there needs to be another filter to ensure the word length. I'm ok with using PCRE or any other standard bash tools.

dude a good trick is often just pipe it through 2 or more regexes

@Fattie simple is best?

it sure is - always in programming

grep -Eixv '.{0,3}|[^u]*|.*[^bluntam].*' /usr/share/dict/words

Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Make sure to cover the most difficult cases for the regexp you want to match and, more importantly, not match despite being very similar to matching input. Without that to test against to prove it works, its hard to say just by reading any given ""fancy regex" if it actually works or not.

How about this?
Positive lookahead for u, then match 4+ characters?
grep -P '^(?=.*u)[bluntam]{4,}$' /usr/share/dict/words

https://regex101.com/r/7UM5Yr/2

This will work with grep using the -P flag for using Perl-compatible regular expressions

The regex you linked didn't have ^ so matched "stuna". But I think with ^ and $ it's correct

Updated, forgot to add the anchor to the linked version.

grep (without perl regex) is not the best tool to and-combine regular expressions. sed or awk would be easier to use. Example with GNU sed (for the case-insensitive I modifier):
sed -En '/u/I{/^[bluntam]{4,}$/Ip}' /usr/share/dict/words

Or with any sed that supports extended regex:
sed -En '/[uU]/{/^[bluntamBLUNTAM]{4,}$/p}' /usr/share/dict/words

With GNU awk (for the case-insensitive IGNORECASE variable):
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/u/ && /^[bluntam]{4,}$/' /usr/share/dict/words

Or, with any awk:
awk '/[uU]/ && /^[bluntamBLUNTAM]{4,}$/' /usr/share/dict/words


Using a positive lookahhead, you can optionally match the allowed characters without the u, and then match it to prevent unnecessary backtracking
^(?=[blntam]*u)[bluntam]{4,}$

Regex demo
Using gnu grep with -P for a perl style regular expression:
grep -iP '^(?=[blntam]*u)[bluntam]{4,}$' /usr/share/dict/words


Interesting, is that more efficient than just .*?

@qwr Using .* will first match until the end of the string, and will then backtrack to the first occurrence of u When you use the character class  [blntam]* then there is no backtracking from the end of the string, as it can not cross matching the u
